# Disabling input method inside a math formula in Emacs with AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am typing a math document in Russian using Emacs 24.3.1 and AUCTeX 11.87. I am using the `russian-computer` input method to type Russian. It would be very convenient to disable this input method inside math delimiters such as `\( \)` so that inside formulas I automatically switch to typing English without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd>. For example, I could type "Рассмотрим формулу \(\)" ("Consider the formula \(\)"), put the point between the parentheses and start typing `\forall`. Currently, I would be typing `\ащкфдд`, but I would like Emacs to recognize that I am inside a formula and switch off the Russian input method.

I suspect that this can be done using `post-self-insert-hook` and `texmathp` from AUCTeX, but I am not sure if this is the most elegant method.

Comment: You might get better answers at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to the problem at http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-08/msg00200.html The code works almost as expected. But drawback is that one can't switch to English from e.g. Russian outside of math delimiters.

This function does the job: switch between english and your current input method.

```
(defun LaTeX-dynamic-input-method-toggle-maybe ()
  (when (or (and current-input-method
             (texmathp))
        (and (not current-input-method)
             (not (texmathp))))
    (toggle-input-method)))
```

"Define a minor-mode, so this behaviour can be conviniently
enabled/disabled. The minor-mode puts the above function on the
`post-command-hook', so that the above function gets called
everytime you do something (e.g. move point)."

```
(define-minor-mode LaTeX-dynamic-input-method
  "Dynamically disable input-method in math-mode."
   nil nil nil
  (if LaTeX-dynamic-input-method
      (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'LaTeX-dynamic-input-method-toggle-maybe nil t)
    (remove-hook 'post-command-hook 'LaTeX-dynamic-input-method-toggle-maybe t)))
```

Enable the mode in LaTeX-mode.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-dynamic-input-method)
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit instead of just show the code